# Downloading images using Asynchronous Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I want to download some pictures from the website at the same time using the Task in C #. The application hangs when call WaitAll (). Here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };

List<Task<byte[]>> tasks = new List<Task<byte[]>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string url = string.Format("http://www.myurl.com/files//53/{0}page.jpg",i);
            Task<byte[]> download = ProcessURLAsync(url, client);
            tasks.Add(download);
        }

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

And method ProcessURLAsync:

```
async Task<byte[]> ProcessURLAsync(string url, HttpClient client)
    {
        var byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` Since `Task.WaitAll` blocks the calling thread.

On a side note, you can use the same instance of HttpClient :) It is designed for multiple concurrent requests. See the remark section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You *can* share an instance, but each instance will have it's own connection pool, which may throttle your throughput.  The entire point here was to avoid that, and get simultaneous downloads.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Sorry `which may throttle` doesn't say anything to me. Does it or not? My own experiences don't show anything like what you say.

Comment: It depends on how many connections you're trying to do at once.  You will only succeed with as many downloads as the connection pool allows for a single instance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Task.WaitAll`, you should use `await Task.WhenAll`.  This will asynchronously wait for the tasks to complete.  `Task.WaitAll` blocks *by design* until the tasks are all completed.

On a side note, each request should use it's own `HttpClient` instance.

Comment: I think such perf optimizations as using multiple `HttpClient` instances should be done only if you can measure single instance as being a bottleneck and also measure the change making a difference.